# How Do I Unit Testing Using Mockito My Product Stream Method?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockito

```
@Test
    fun `getProductStream should return PagingData`() = runBlocking {
        // Mock data yang akan digunakan oleh repository
        val mockPagingData = PagingData.from(listOf(/* ... list of mock products ... */))

        // Mock metode getProducts pada dao dan coEvery untuk mengembalikan mockPagingData
        coEvery { database.productDao().getProduct() } returns flowOf(mockPagingData)

        // Panggil metode yang akan diuji
        val resultFlow = repository.getProductStream()

        // Collect hasil dari flow
        resultFlow.collect { pagingData ->
            // Pastikan pagingData yang diterima tidak kosong atau sesuai dengan ekspektasi
            assert(pagingData is PagingData<Product>)
            // Anda dapat melakukan asser lebih lanjut sesuai dengan kebutuhan Anda
        }
    }
```

I got stuck when unit testing using mockito in that method.I just want to chect that the data is not empty and the datasource is gets called in the process.

Below was the example of unit testing that i build

```
 @Test
    fun getProductById(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val responseGetProductById = mockk<Response<ResponseBuyerProductById>>()
        every {
            runBlocking {
                repository.getProductById(1)
            }
        } returns responseGetProductById

        repository.getProductById(1)

        verify {
            runBlocking {
                repository.getProductById(1)
            }
        }

    }
```